# Calling events on SAPUI5 Controls

Tags: sapui5

I am developing an SAPUI5 application that contains user configurations and user capability to move the screen around.
i.e. Let's assume that the screen is a Dynamic Side Content Layout `sap.ui.layout.DynamicSideContent` with an option with the user to either place it on the left or right. The user also has an option to close/open the side content based on their usage.

To facilitate this, there is a button (see snapshots below) which gives the user a pullout kind of feeling on the screen. The button has absolute position so its width is calculated based on the browser window and the side content's size and position.To calculate the first time the screen is rendered, I have used
`window.load event.

[image]
[image]
But it does not behave properly in all scenarios. How can I trigger **renderComplete** event on the layout(for that matter, on any `sap.ui.core.Control`). I have tried using the following code but none of the events were triggered.

```
controlName.addEventDelegate({
                onBeforeShow: function() {
                    console.log("on Before Show");
                },
                onAfterShow: function() {
                    console.log("on After Show")
                }
            })
```

I can't use `onAfterRendering` of the view since it is called before the Page is loaded with all dependent resources and the `$.load()` function does not work as well.

What could be the best approach for a scenario like this?

Thanks in Advance

Edit: Adding my Code.

```
onAfterRendering: function(){
        var dynamicContainer= this.getView().byId("idKPIWORDynamicSideContent");
            dynamicContainer.addDelegate({
                onAfterRendering: function(){
                    alert("After Rendering");
                }   
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Control's `onAfterRendering` method as below:

For e.g. `sap.m.ComboBox` control,

```
oComboBox.onAfterRendering = function(){
    if (sap.m.ComboBox.prototype.onAfterRendering){
        sap.m.ComboBox.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this);
    }
    // your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a case which might be similar from the technical point of view. I had to color table cells after the data binding based on the value of the cell. This solved my issue. Here "this" is controller. So I would suggest to put the following code in onAfterRendering() of your controller.

```
control.addDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: $.proxy(this.functionToExecute, control)
});
```

Comment: Hi Shidai, I tried doing this inside the onAfterRendering of the View, but that doesn't seem to call the function at all. Example in the question above

Comment: Put it in the onAfterRendering of your controller. 'this' then will be your controller, where you need to add a new function functionToExecute. 'control' in this case is something like this.getView().byid('controlId')